# FileNotFoundException from java spring boot app while using URI.create(url).toURL().openStream()

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, filenotfoundexception

Through my spring boot app, i am trying to read a url string which contains pdf file by using below code.

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
inputStream = URI.create(url).toURL().openStream()
```

url is https://www.sample.com/example.pdf

When it reaches the URI code, it throws the `FileNotFoundException` in the application server. Same code works fine in my local machine(both mac and windows).

Any idea on the issue fix

Trying to copy the pdf file from the remote url into local folder

Tried both `NIO` and `InputStreamReader` as mentioned in the below website

https://www.baeldung.com/java-download-file

Answer (score 0):

It is resolved. The site which I try to fetch the pdf file is taking sometime to load the pdf in the remote url.
Increasing the thread sleeping time to wait until its generated. So issue is resolved